# Password Catch Based on Selections on Form

Tags: excel, forms, vba, parameters, passwords

New to this site and VBA in general, so hopefully my posting here will help me find an answer. Thank you all in advance for advice you have!

Here's my situation and question:

At my office, a report generator tool was created to help managers pull excel sheet data and spit out a cross-reference report. The report is generated based on the parameters that the user selects.

There is a condition that if the user selects "Employee Name" in one paramter field, and they select "Total Direct Labor Dollars", "Sell", or "Total Labor Prime" in another field, they would be required to enter in a password to proceed. The code I currently have IS asking the user for a password... but it's asking for it as long as "Employee Name" is selected, regardless of any field selected in the other.

```
    Sub FormattingNums(critNum As Long, repSelNum As Long, Month As String, Year As String, _
    MonthNum As Long, YearNum As Long, reportNum As Long, dateDiff As Long, dateDiffYear As Long, _
    dateDiffMonth As Long, byWeek As Boolean, autoFormat As Boolean, monthSummary As Boolean, weekSummary As Boolean, _
    Mode2013 As Boolean, chartmaker As Boolean, title As String)

    Dim lCount      As Long     'Counter for going through list
    Dim formCheck   As Boolean  'For LevelDepth Selection
    Dim rCount      As Long     'Counter for going through report list
    Dim pw          As Boolean
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    byWeek = frmNewProjectReport.chbByWeek.Value 'Boolean user selection
    autoFormat = frmNewProjectReport.chbAutoFormat.Value 'Boolean user selection
    monthSummary = frmNewProjectReport.chbSumMonth.Value 'Boolean user selection
    chartmaker = frmNewProjectReport.chbChart.Value 'Boolean user selection
    title = frmNewProjectReport.txtProjectName      'String of Report title

    dateDiffYear = frmNewProjectReport.cmbEndYear.Value - frmNewProjectReport.cmbBeginYear.Value 'Integer
    dateDiffMonth = frmNewProjectReport.cmbEndMonth.Value - frmNewProjectReport.cmbBeginMonth.Value 'Integer
    dateDiff = (dateDiffYear * 12) + dateDiffMonth 'Integer
    MonthNum = frmNewProjectReport.cmbBeginMonth.Value 'Number
    YearNum = frmNewProjectReport.cmbBeginYear.Value 'Number
    Month = MonthNum 'String
    Year = YearNum 'String
    If (MonthNum < 2 And YearNum = 2014) Or (YearNum < 2014) Then
        Mode2013 = True
    End If

    reportNum = frmNewProjectReport.txtReportQuant 'Number of reports chosen
    critNum = 0
    repSelNum = 0
    With frmNewProjectReport.lbxCriteria    'Counts number of criteria choices selected
        For lCount = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(lCount) = True Then
                'For selection of levels
                If .List(lCount) = "Level" Then
                    frmLevelDepthSelection.Show
                    If frmLevelDepthSelection.cmbLevelSelection.Value = "Levels" Then
                        formCheck = False
                        Do While formCheck = False
                            MsgBox "You must select a Level to Continue", vbExclamation, "Report Creation Assistant"
                            frmLevelDepthSelection.Show
                            If frmLevelDepthSelection.cmbLevelSelection.Value <> "Levels" Then
                                formCheck = True
                            End If
                        Loop
                    End If
                ElseIf .List(lCount) = "Employee Name" Then
                    With frmNewProjectReport.lbxReport
                        For rCount = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                            If .List(rCount) = "Cost" _
                            Or .List(rCount) = "Total Direct Labor Dollars" _
                            Or .List(rCount) = "Sell" _
                            Or .List(rCount) = "Total Labor Prime" Then
                                Do While pw = False
                                    frmHourlyRate.Show
                                    If frmHourlyRate.txtHourlyRate.Value = "BMAccess" Then
                                        pw = True
                                    Else
                                        MsgBox "Incorrect password", vbOKOnly, "Incorrect Password"
                                    End If
                                Loop
                            End If
                        Next rCount
                    End With
                End If
                critNum = critNum + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
    With frmNewProjectReport.lbxReport 'Counts number of report choices selected
        For lCount = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(lCount) = True Then
                repSelNum = repSelNum + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks again everyone!

*edit: I added the entire Sub so you guys can see. Not sure if it'll help, but can't do no harm :). Thanks again!

Comment: Can you share the complete `IF` condition ?

Comment: Is it working now based on the answer by @Bond?

Comment: No, no luck yet. All it does now is bypass the password function altogether, regardless of what values are selected.

Comment: `parameters that the user selects...`, what exactly is this `frmNewProjectReport`?

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating the entire listbox and testing each string against your values, so you're always going to match, as long as those strings exist as list items.

You need to check the *selected* value against your strings.

Change:

```
For rCount = 0 To .ListCount - 1
    If .List(rCount) = "Cost" _
    Or .List(rCount) = "Total Direct Labor Dollars" _
    Or .List(rCount) = "Sell" _
    Or .List(rCount) = "Total Labor Prime" Then
```

To:

```
If .Text = "Cost" _
Or .Text = "Total Direct Labor Dollars" _
Or .Text = "Sell" _
Or .Text = "Total Labor Prime" Then
```

It looks like you may be doing it wrong for your `"Employee Name"` listbox as well.

Comment: Thanks for your input Bond! I just changed the code as you suggested, but now it's not even asking for a password even if those parameters are selected. Any thoughts?

Comment: Step through your code in the debugger and check to see where we're going off the rails. Is it passing the first test (`"Employee Name"`) but failing the second or vice versa. Also of note, `=` does a case-sensitive comparison so you'll need to ensure your listbox contains the same case as the text you're comparing against.

Comment: It's passing through everything. Case matches, so it's not a case sensitivity issue. Just stepped through and it does check the fields... and keeps on going after the OR conditions :(. Is "For rCount = 0 To .ListCount - 1" supposed to remain by the way?

Comment: If you hover over the `.Text` property, does it show the proper selected item's text.

Comment: This is the message I'm getting: .Text = <Object variable or With block variable not set>

Comment: OK. Did you keep your `With frmNewProjectReport.lbxReport` line? You'll still need that to be there.

Comment: Yes sir, I did. Didn't touch anything beyond what you suggested to change.

Comment: Interesting. If it's a standard listbox, it should have a `Text` property. We could try removing the `With` statement and writing out the full property name (`frmNewProjectReport.lbxReport.Text`). Intellisense should pop up and help you out when doing this so hopefully you see the `Text` property appear after hitting that last dot.

Comment: I added the entire sub at the top. Not sure what needs to be changed since I'm getting errors now :(... thank you again for helping me out, and any continuous help is of course very much appreciated.